# Superclass method using overridden subclass methods

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, overriding

This is a strangely worded question so I apologize if it's a duplicate.

Say I have a class `foo` with method `a` that calls method `b`:

```
public class foo
{
    public void a()
    {
       b();
    }

    public void b()
    {
       gamma();
    }
}
```

Now I have a subclass `bar` that extends `foo`

```
public class bar extends foo
{
    @Override
    public void b()
    {
       theta();
    }
}
```

If I call `bar.a()`, will `a` use the `b` method from the superclass or the `b` method from the subclass? That is, will `bar.b()` end up executing `gamma` or will it end up executing `theta`?

Comment: There is no problem in asking but since you have the code written you could just check it yourself by logging or just writing it to the console. I am always happy to make experiments of this kind to se what will happen - that way you can sometimes find new ways of doing something you might not indented at this moment but later on you will find it useful to have done it already. You might reinvent the wheel sometimes but with the curiosity and by doing all kind of small stuff by yourself you learn a lot more than just getting the answer

Answer (score 1):

It will use method b from the subclass.  This is the point of overriding methods.  A subclass extending its parent is free to create more specific implementations of a method.  When the overridden method is called on the sublcass, its specialized method will be used in place of the super class's method.

Answer (score 0):

> f I call bar.a(), will a use the b method from the superclass or the b
>   method from the subclass? That is, will bar.b() end up executing gamma
>   or will it end up executing theta?

It will use `bar.b()` method. This is the result of **[dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).**